# Did S. Korea choose petroleum refining as part of WW2 reconstruction?

Tags: economy

I just noticed (on Wikipedia) that S. Korea has 3 and the 6 largest oil refineries *in the world*. That does not make sense. So, was exporting the derivatives of crude oil (gasoline / kerosene / jet fuel / etc) part of their centrally-planned economic reconstruction strategy after ww2??

I mean, Korea copied the Japanese success in exporting autos and consumer electronics. But, did Korea centrally-plan to also export oil derivatives as part of their economic recovery from the devastation of ww2?

Comment: Industrialization of Korea only bgan in the 1970s. The Korean War broke out after WW2. Yes, it was centrally planned when it started, but I don't understand your question. Korea was lucky to have China as a neighbor and its oil refinery industry grew rapidly thanks to China's rapid economic growth. It doesn't necessarily mean it was centrally-planned to export oil derivatives.

Comment: @Rathony Any pipelines to China would go through N. Korea. And Western technology is required to build and maintain them. So, no pipelines to China. The petroleum products are put on giant ships to be sent across the very narrow Yellow Sea? But there is no competitive advantage to using ships. There must be government subsidies to the refiners. With no competitive advantage why did government / chaebol get into the refining business is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humorously enough (considering the recent U.S. election), Korea is probably one of the best examples of economic growth via rejecting globalism and classical economics theory (see anything by [Ha-Joon Chang](http://hajoonchang.net)).  However, President Park, in the 1970s embarked on one of the possibly less successful growth approaches used by the Korean government (clearly in general his strong government-industry coupling and import controls were wildly successful, as the country rapidly moved from poverty-stricken to wealthy), which was the [Heavy and Chemical Industrialization Program of 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-Chemical_Industry_Drive).  The idea was to support a slew of "heavy industries" (rather loosely defined) to help the overall competitiveness of Korean industry.  A good paper on this (a tad on the critical side) is [Korea's experience with industrial adjustment in the 1970's](https://www.kdevelopedia.org/Resources/all/koreas-experience-with-industrial-adjustment-1970s--04201203270113599.do;jsessionid=9DB8C09EDB8BC602FEA150F0DBDE5761#.WG8TjBTmZex).  Petroleum refineries were a component of this program.

Comment: "Korea is probably one of the best examples of economic growth via rejecting globalism and classical economics theory"

How so? What supports this statement?

Comment: Among other things, Korea used extreme levels of import controls throughout the 70s.  That is a rejection of globalism and classical economics.  And it certainly had economic growth.  Park actually exceeded his goals for economic development.  http://www.tradingeconomics.com/south-korea/gdp-per-capita (click MAX).  One book on this is Bad Samaritans (Ha-Joon Chang).

Comment: Protective tariffs mean in practice that citizens give collectively additional money to the internal industry. The idea that it leads to stagnation or poverty is controversial... probably anywhere outside the United States.

Comment: @kubanczyk the EU is much more pro-free trade than the US